# text hyphenation within a html button

Tags: html, css, button, text, hyphenation

I have a Button with a fixed width. Within this button there is a `<b>` tag with the name in it.
The name is variable and it can be longer than the width of the button.

When viewed in a browser, the longer text doesn't fit in the button. 
Is there a way to hyphenate the button text?  The text doesn't have "spaces" but underscores: "_".

Comment: Is this you are looking for http://jsbin.com/jixoviqa/1/edit?

Comment: Do you want to show hyphen when a word breaks, or show it to indicate that some text is hidden..? and what do you mean by "within this button there is a tag with the name in it" ? what tag..? can you add some sample code and a better description..? hope the answer helps

Comment: Is it permissible to break the text after an underscore? And if you really mean hyphenation, is it OK to manually add hyphenation hints, or should you be able to do it programmatically? Is the language of the text in the button known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want a long text appear in limited width button. have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jixoviqa/1/edit)** First.

**CSS**

```
#test{
  display: block;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="test">text_hyphenation_within_a_html_button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property to specify a custom string to be used to represent clipped text. For example,

HTML

```
<div>
 some overflowing text
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
 width:25px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px solid;
 overflow:hidden;
 white-space:nowrap;
 text-overflow: "_";
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rz6Ph/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `text-overlow:'_';`. To make overflowing text do this use the following CSS:

```
button{
    width:100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '_';
  white-space: nowrap;
}    

<button>My text is to long for me!</button>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/2jq4S/2/)
Ellipsis (...) can also be used by `text-overlow:ellipsis;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this using "hyphens" CSS property. [Read More about Word Hypernation](http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/)

```
.button{
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
width:90px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8UPX/)

Comment: Just to add, this is the browser compatibility for hyphens: http://caniuse.com/css-hyphens